# Rendering ErrorPage shape manually in Orchard

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, orchardcms, custom-errors, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/472090

Can we get the ErrorPage shape to render by a specific route like ~/Error/ErrorPage or something? 500 errors serve the Runtime Error page in my site and I'd like to redirect those via customErrors to the default ErrorPage or Orchard instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a controller and create a route that points to it. From your controller action, throw an exception.

Comment: was hoping there was a specific route already out there. thanks for this! i decided to create a template for the AccessDenied shape instead